# PHPExcel Codeigniter-4 unable to upload more than 50k rows

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

I want to upload an excel file of 50K  rows but it's unable to read them while I upload 2k row its worked fine and data was uploaded in the database(MySQL) also but when I tried to upload 50K rows at a time its not even showing error also.So my requirement is to upload 50K rows and 40 columns at  a time using SpreadsheetReader_XLSX

Comment: You can not upload huge data at a time because of memory limit issue. For solving this issue you should chunk your excel file as array and upload it

Comment: so please send me some link for reference

Comment: see the answer. I've given reference code

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So show us the code you are using for this

Answer (score 0):

**Sample code:**

```
$content = ""; //$content value is null when creating
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){//runs ten times
   //set $content for ten times
   $content .= "John,Doe,2021,12,07,".time().",".$i."\n";
}
$myfile = fopen("myexcel.csv", "a");
fwrite($myfile, $content);
fclose($myfile);
```

**output excel *(.csv)* :**

[image: Sample:]:

Answer (score -1):

You are getting error because of memory limit issue of php/mysql. For solving this issue you can chunk your excel file and upload it  to database. Follow the below code as reference.

```
$fileName=uploadFile($_FILES['excelFile'],array(".csv"),"excel_file");
$row=0;
if(($handle = fopen("excel/".$fileName , "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        $num = count($data);
        //print_r($data);
        $query="INSERT INTO StudentData(FirstName,LastName,MobileNo,City)VALUES('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."')";
        //use prepare statement for inserting data by pdo/mysqli prepare
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the file is an `csv` but not if its an `xls` or `xlsx`

Comment: Your answer suggests to use **Bad database coding** with the opertunity for [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: That will also speed up the 50k inserts as you can prepare once and execute once per row in the spreadsheet

Comment: Error
Call to undefined function App\Controllers\uploadFile()

Comment: I am getting error like this

Comment: its a reference code. you should modify it according to your needs

Comment: Its supposed to be an answer, not a starter for 10

Comment: ���f�������PK!����xl/workbook.xml�U]o�0}����=�BԴ�4�m����4��'�l����]'���ҵ؎���{�}y]���!)/B�\�� E�SZ�C�p?3}dH��3^��D�W߿]�ز�����n���Nh ;����{D�fU��������~��������]�����o�������������t}�������~�����~y�/��޿����g�����ﯯ��w�^>����Ǘ������?����������ۻ�?<�������_߭OO�w|����O�������>����훿}��_{��Z|zZo?�����뇗׿}~����o�x~�����w�z�>~��������O_^�����ż"������v������m����������������y�?�����������7�����OX����*C˓�|�����o�r�ߞ�}~���K�����ǗO�x�?}��7�����{����׿��4X�Yh6�\��|�-v��\йع���F�ˉ\�����7���ݙ�YRg(�s����ݱ����P

Comment: when i used to print data (print_r($data);)  i am getting output like this

Comment: Thats because as I said in comment 1 **that code wont work for an `.xls` or an `.xlsx` file**

Comment: have you ever used PHPOffice library?

Comment: require_once(APPPATH . "ThirdParty/php-excel-reader/SpreadsheetReader.php");
         yeah i have used